# same fontsize in plot in revtex document as text

Tags: pstricks, miktex, fontsize, two-column, revtex

I am making a figure in PSTricks for a RevTeX document. A MWE of my figure is the following

```
\documentclass{article}[28pt]
\usepackage{pstricks, pst-node, pst-plot, pst-circ}
\usepackage{moredefs}

\usepackage[ansinew]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{amsmath, amsthm, amssymb}

\begin{document}

\rput[t](-2.5600000,0.254261){$-2.5$}
\end{document}
```

When I change the fontsize, the -2.5 is unchanged. I don't understand why that is?

That being said, the main goal I have is to use `10pt`, just like TwoColumn RevTeX uses. But the problem is that when I include my PStricks-figure in my main document with `includegrapghics`, then the fontsize will become smaller, because I make the figure smaller by `width=\columnwidth`. Is there a strategy I can use such that the picture has the same fontsize as the text in my RevTeX document?

Comment: There is no `28pt` option for `article`. Just issue `\fontsize{28}{36}\selectfont` before the `\rput` command.

Comment: @egreg I will do that - but it will not solve the problem that the effective fontsize becomes smaller when I insert the picture in the `RevTex` document

Comment: Why don't you make a smaller plot?

Comment: @egreg Wow, you mean simply making the pdf smaller before inserting? I did not know that is possible.. how does one do that?

Comment: @egreg should I use `\pdfpaperheight=11in` and `\pdfpaperwidth=8.5in`

Comment: I mean that *you* are stating the dimensions of the graphic you're creating with PSTricks, aren't you? Can you make a more realistic example?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your question is a bit sparse on details.  But here I'll illustrate a method for creating a `pdf` as a separate file and then importing it into another document.  The key here is to scale the first `pdf` so that, when it's imported, font-sizes and such are sized appropriately.

If you know the dimensions you want for the embedded image, you can set the `unit` for `pstricks` accordingly to that the font is the desired size in the imported image.

For example, if I create the **unscaled** image:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pstricks,pst-node}
\pagestyle{empty}
\begin{document}
\begin{pspicture}[showgrid](-10,-10)(10,10)
  \rput(-8,8){Hello}
  \rput(8,-8){World}
\end{pspicture}
\end{document}
```

and then embed it, by importing it, in another document, as here:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\pagestyle{empty}
\begin{document}

\lipsum[1]

\includegraphics[height=2in]{example_01}

\lipsum[2]

\end{document}
```

you get a rather unsatisfactory result

[image]

But you can scale the original `pstricks` image as follows by adding `\psset{unit=...}` and setting `unit` to an appropriate value

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pstricks,pst-node}
\pagestyle{empty}
\begin{document}

\psset{unit=0.1in}

\begin{pspicture}[showgrid](-10,-10)(10,10)
  \rput(-8,8){Hello}
  \rput(8,-8){World}
\end{pspicture}
\end{document}
```

Then, when you import it, you get:

[image]