# Same pgfplots within standalone for usage in elsarticle and revtex4-1

Tags: pgfplots, best-practices, standalone, revtex, elsarticle

Suppose I have created a plot with `pgfplots` for a scientific paper.

However, for usual reasons the targeted journal is not certain. Possibly the plot has to be adjusted to match different journals (consider here `revtex4-1` and `elsarticle`). This includes font type, font sizes, columnwidths/textwidths.

For instance, the values of the `\columnwidth` differ:

```
% \documentclass[preprint,5p,twocolumn,12pt]{elsarticle}
\the\columnwidth=252.0pt
% \documentclass[aps,final,pre,twocolumn,10pt]{revtex4-1}
\the\columnwidth=246.0pt
```

I have considered the package `standalone`:

plot.tex:

```
\documentclass[class=elsarticle,5p,twocolumn,12pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.5}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
width=\columnwidth,
title=Inv. cum. normal,
xlabel={$x$},
ylabel={$y$},
]
\addplot[blue] table {invcum.dat};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[download invcum.dat](https://github.com/live-clones/pgfplots/blob/master/doc/latex/pgfplots/plotdata/invcum.dat)

paper.tex:

```
\documentclass[preprint,5p,twocolumn,12pt]{elsarticle}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\begin{document}
\setlength{\parindent}{0ex}
\lipsum[1]\vspace*{2ex}
\begin{figure}
  \centering
  \includegraphics{plot}
  \caption{interesting results}
\end{figure}
\vspace*{2ex}\lipsum[2]
\end{document}
```

After the paper got rejected :(, the documentclass gets changed.

paper.tex

```
\documentclass[final,aps,pre,twocolumn,10pt]{revtex4-1}
```

plot.tex

```
\documentclass[class=revtex4-1,final,aps,pre,twocolumn,10pt]{standalone}
```

For some reason `standalone` fails to accept as class option `revtex4-1`.

What would be a good workflow to minimize the workload using `pdflatex` without using dvi-eps path. Quantities, which should be available to plotting, are font size, `\columnwidth` and `\textwidth`.

An answer with a gnuplot+standalone solution would be a good addition.

Related questions:

- The answer
  '[same fontsize in plot in revtex document as text](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/124833/same-fontsize-in-plot-in-revtex-document-as-text)' gives a suggestion to adjust the font size in pstricks manually.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `\includestandalone` from `standalone` package (requires `-shell-escape`).

`plot.tex`:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.5}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
width=\columnwidth,
title=Inv. cum. normal,
xlabel={$x$},
ylabel={$y$},
]
\addplot[blue] table {invcum.dat};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Then in `elsarticle`:

```
\documentclass[preprint,twocolumn,12pt]{elsarticle}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{graphicx}
%\usepackage{pgfplots}
%\pgfplotsset{compat=1.5}
\usepackage[subpreambles=true]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\setlength{\parindent}{0ex}
\lipsum[1]\vspace*{2ex}
\begin{figure}
  \centering
  \includestandalone[mode=buildnew]{plot}
  %\includegraphics{plot}
  \caption{interesting results}
\end{figure}
\vspace*{2ex}\lipsum[2]
\end{document}
```

[image]

And in `revtex4-1`

```
\documentclass[final,aps,pre,twocolumn,10pt]{revtex4-1}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{graphicx}
%\usepackage{pgfplots}
%\pgfplotsset{compat=1.5}
\usepackage[subpreambles=true]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\setlength{\parindent}{0ex}
\lipsum[1]\vspace*{2ex}
\begin{figure}
  \centering
  \includestandalone[mode=buildnew]{plot}
  %\includegraphics{plot}
  \caption{interesting results}
\end{figure}
\vspace*{2ex}\lipsum[2]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Now, for curiosity, try with a big font size and different font.

```
\documentclass[18pt]{scrartcl}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{mathpazo}
\usepackage{graphicx}
%\usepackage{pgfplots}
%\pgfplotsset{compat=1.5}
\usepackage[subpreambles=true]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\setlength{\parindent}{0ex}
\lipsum[1]\vspace*{2ex}
\begin{figure}
  \centering
  \includestandalone[mode=buildnew]{plot}
  %\includegraphics{plot}
  \caption{interesting results}
\end{figure}
\vspace*{2ex}\lipsum[2]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: @Kumar: Thank you for your answer. However, when I submit a paper I like to keep the number of required packages small. I would prefer `paper.tex` does not have to know about standalone and I don't have to adjust the file for submission. Do you know how one could achieve this?

Comment: @Hotschke Not any of that I am aware of. You may remove those packages at very last stage before submitting.

Comment: To my knowledge, journals usually prefer to receive the figures as graphics files (eg .eps), instead of .tex